Why are internal energy and work mentioned in a question about exothermic or endothermic systems?
This is a question from my chemistry homework.  Note the explanation below.

A 100.0-g bar of gold is heated from 25°C to 50°C during which it absorbs 322 J of heat. The volume of the gold bar remains constant.
Ans: Process is endothermic


A balloon is cooled by removing 0.651 kJ of heat. It shrinks on cooling, and the atmosphere does 0.381 J of work on the balloon.
Ans: Process is exothermic


[Explanation:] The heated bar of gold performs no work, so its internal energy only increases and the system is endothermic. The gain of energy from work performed on the balloon is less than the loss of energy through heat, so there is a net loss of internal energy in the balloon and the system is exothermic.



Usually processes are called exo-, and endothermic, not systems.

Enthalpy-H and Energy-U are state functions; it makes no difference if they are lowered by removing heat or by the system doing work when the beginning and end states are the same for both processes. A liter of gasoline in your car releases the same amount of energy when burned while idling or driving10K. As to your comment context is important. Using propane to grill a burger is different from using it to propel a car.

The terms endothermic refer to the direction of heat flow in the process, not to the internal energy or temperature change.

Exothermic processes cause heat being transferred out of a system OR thermal energy of a system being increased (or both). And vice versa.
Even the etymology of terms suggests such processes are either a heat source either a heat sink.
As a process is meant an internal change of a system state, not events happening on the system/surrounding interface.

Consider isothermic compression of an ideal gas in a closed system.

Think again. It is isothermic compression, not adiabatic compression.

That's what I said.  I said it was neither exothermic nor endothermic, which is isothermic.  So I don't know why I would need to "think again."

I apologize, I should should write isothermal compression (T2 = T1), not to be confused with isothermic (Q=0) as border between exothermic and endothermic.

It really is imho terrible nomenclature. Isothermal is used to mean constant temperature and in the context of an ideal gas it makes sense to associate this with constant thermal energy, but it is afaiu not universally true.

Note that in most contexts isothermic and isothermal are used interchangeably to mean at constant temperature (I do so), even if upon closer inspection they can be interpreted differently.

@BuckThorn Isothermal for constant T, adiabatic for Q=0 and all should be clear. // I get regularly suddenly unsure about proper suffixes of some English adjectives generally, not limited to chemistry. Note that the majority of my EN knowledge came after gaining majority of my chemistry knowledge, so sometimes I can mess things....  :-)

exo- and endo- are Greek ("outside of" and "inside of") so it should be transcendental but instead adds confusion. And "thermos" means "heat"!

I have once heard from EN-US native story writer that English is the most confusing language. :-)

I'm not a professional chemist, but it seems off-point to me.  I'm just trying to get a straight answer to a homework question.  It's frustrating that no one can give me true/false answers or just answer with the resulting number from an equation when that's exactly what they expect us to do in class.

My professor is always saying things like it's fuzzy and depands on circumstances and you never know and such, and I think, "Is it fuzzy when you put it on an exam and ask us to answer it?  Can I write that on my exam?"  Me on the exam: "There are all kinds of situations, and different things can happen, and there really are no set answers in chemistry."
